# $scope variable inexplicably not being set

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs 'child' directive, thus:

```
someAlertMessage: function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span ng-show="showAlert">whatever</span>',
        require: '^someInput',
        controller: function($scope, AcmeService){
            $scope.setShowAlert = function(aValue){

                AcmeService.getThings(aValue, function(data){ // bog standard http get with callback
                    console.log(data) // THIS LOGS true
                    $scope.showAlert = true; // THIS WORKS
                    $scope.showAlert = data; // THIS DOESNT WORK
                }

            }
        }
        link: function(scope, e, a, c){
            scope.$watch('someinputvalue', function(nv, ov){
                scope.setShowAlert(nv)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the markup of the page where these directives are used:

```
<someInput>
    <someAlertMessage></someAlertMessage>
</someInput>
```

There isn't much of any interest about the 'someInput' parent directive. The only thing to note is that `transclude:true` in the directive and in the markup:

```
<div>
    <!-- things -->
    <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

As noted in the first listing, I have two cases:

- hard coding the `$scope.showAlert` variable to true within the service callback has exactly the desired effect: the scope is updated and the DOM changes accordingly to show the span
- setting the $scope variable to the value returned from the service (which I know to be `true`, via logging & debugging) does nothing. In this case, if I write the `$scope.showAlert` value out to the screen, it stays false.

I've tried hardcoding the return value from the service to `true`, without making the http call, and this also gives the desired effect

So, i'm stumped, what can I do? Let me know what more info is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try wrapping your service call in a `$scope.$apply()` block? It may be that because of the way the service is getting called, the DOM isn't aware of the update when the service returns a result. Wrapping the call in an apply is a quick way to test that.

Comment: @ajk thanks for the suggestion - wrapping the call in $scope.$apply has no effect - all cases respond as before.

Comment: it logs true or "true"? you see my point... if you use firebug try [AngScope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/), a tiny extention i wrote. it will help you inspect $scope objects associated with DOM elements.

Comment: suggest creating live demo that replicates problem

Comment: $scope.showAlert = data === 'true'; is what @KosProv is suggesting.

Comment: It logs the boolean value `true`, not a string 'true', if that's what you're meaning.